# Capture all strings that start with "[[" and end with "]]" as regex while splitting

Tags: java, regex, scala

Currently I'm using `str.toLowerCase.split("[\\s\\W]+")` to get rid of white space and punctuation, but there's a special class of strings I'd like to keep as one and exclude from this treatment:

```
[[...multiple words...]]
```

Example:

```
[[Genghis Khan]]
```

should remain as

```
[[Genghis Khan]]
```

What kind of regex should I use?

Comment: FYI, the set of characters matched by `\W` includes whitespace characters, so you don't need the `\s`. `"\\W+"` will suffice.

Answer (score 8):

Your regular expression isn't so far off:

```
def tokenize(s: String) = """\w+|(\[\[[^\]]+\]\])""".r.findAllIn(s).toList
```

And then:

```
scala> tokenize("[[Genghis Khan]] founded the [[Mongol Empire]].")
res1: List[String] = List([[Genghis Khan]], founded, the, [[Mongol Empire]])
```

This is a nice use case for Scala's [parser combinators](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/util/parsing/combinator/package.html), though:

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator._

object Tokenizer extends RegexParsers {
  val punc = "[,;:\\.]*".r
  val word = "\\w+".r
  val multiWordToken = "[[" ~> "[^\\]]+".r <~ "]]"
  val token = (word | multiWordToken) <~ punc
  def apply(s: String) = parseAll(token+, s)
}
```

Which similarly gives us:

```
scala> Tokenizer("[[Genghis Khan]] founded the [[Mongol Empire]].").get
res2: List[String] = List(Genghis Khan, founded, the, Mongol Empire)
```

I prefer the parser combinator version, personally—it's practically self-documenting and much easier to extend and maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a function that splits first on either `[[` or `]]`.  Doing this ensure that the split items alternate between unquoted and quoted strings (ie, the 2nd, 4th, etc items are "quoted").  Then we can traverse this list and split any unquoted items on whitespace while leaving quoted items untouched.

```
def mySplit(s: String) = 
  """(\[\[)|(\]\])""".r.split(s).zipWithIndex.flatMap { 
    case (unquoted, i) if i%2==0 => unquoted.trim.split("\\s+")
    case (quoted, _) => List(quoted)
  }.toList.filter(_.nonEmpty)

mySplit("this [[is]] the first [[test string]].") // List(this, is, the, first, test string, .)
mySplit("[[this]] and [[that]]")          // List(this, and, that)
mySplit("[[this]][[that]][[the other]]")  // List(this, that, the other)
```

If you want the `[[ ]]` in the final output, then just change the above `List(quoted)` to `List("[[" + quoted + "]]")`

Answer (score 0):

Split is not the way to handle this, because it doesn't handle context. You might have written this:

```
str.toLowerCase.split("(?<!\\[\\[([^]]|\\][^]])*\\]?)[\\s\\W]+")
```

which would split on any space that is not preceded by `[[` followed by anything except `]]`, but Java doesn't like variable-size look-behinds.

In my opinion, the best way to handle this is write a parser for it, unless you really need speed. Use a regex like suggested by [Travis Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/334519/travis-brown) (who also showed a parser in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10402396/53013)).